# Accessing key in an Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
RaceArray: [{
    Unknown: 0,
    Caucasian: 1,
    AfricanAmerican: 2,
    AmericanIndian: 3,
    Asian: 4,
    Hispanic: 5,
    Other: 6
 }]
```

How can i access the key's alone in my JavaScript and form it as an separate array.

Desired outcome...

```
RaceArray = ['Unknown','Caucasian']
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. You've posted the before, maybe post the after (desired outcome)?

Comment: may be you want array like ["unknown","caucasian".....] ?

Comment: Apart from the (not very good) coding question my advise would be to study the concept of *race* first. Start @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(classification_of_humans)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var RaceObj = [{
    Unknown: 0,
    Caucasian: 1,
    AfricanAmerican: 2,
    AmericanIndian: 3,
    Asian: 4,
    Hispanic: 5,
    Other: 6
}];

var obj = RaceObj[0], Keys = [];
for(var key in obj){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    Keys.push(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is RaceObj[0] here... why do we use it.

Comment: @John: In your `RaceArray`, you have an array containing 1 element, an object.  So, `RaceObj[0]` gets that object.  I also renamed `RaceArray` to `RaceObj`.

Answer (score -1):

There may be a simpler solution but you can do:

```
var keys = [];
for(var key in RaceObj) {
    if (RaceObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `RaceObj` is an array **first** and an object **second**. You'll need to iterate the array before retrieving the keys.

Comment: aham i will recommend not to use for (var key in obj) .. instead use jquery's $.each or put if condition checking if the property belongs to object and not its prototype

Comment: You should use `hasOwnProperty` to only get own properties.

Comment: @RizwanSharif: Why involve a jQuery object in this? Are you aware `.each()` [uses for(... in ...) already](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L604-642)?

Comment: When iterating over objects like this, you *always* need to use a `hasOwnProperty` check, otherwise properties that exist on the prototype will be iterated over as well, which is usually not expected behavior.